# Why trace is natural than (preferred to) determinant for smooth map $f:M\to N$?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, pullback

For a continuous map $f:(M,g)\to (N,h)$, between Riemannian manifolds $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$ we can pullback the $h$ by $f$. Most of experts take trace from this new tensor and work with it. i.e. $\mathrm{tr_g}(f^*h)$ which I think is equals to $|df|^2$. I think there is a simple reason from *Linear Algebra* that perhaps I missed it that

> **Question:** why they use trace (e.g. [see this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1702651/272127)) and not determinant or any other operator?

One primary reason is that it is similar to $\mathrm{tr }A^tB$ that is an inner product over $n\times n$ matrices.

In the case of energy density of harmonic maps, $e(f):=\frac{1}{2}|df|^2$ is very natural operator because it is similar to (up to a constant $m$) the [kinetic energy formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy) $E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ in physics.

But these are not sufficient to not consider the determinant (or any other operator) case. I want to know Is the following expression meaningful and can it reveals nice properties of the space as well as trace case? or that is same as trace case?
$$K(f):=\int_M\det_g(f^*h)dvol_g.$$

**Update:** It is also helpful remember that the trace is $\sum_i\lambda_i$ and determinant is $\prod_i\lambda_i$.

Comment: The trace is a linear object while the determinant is polynomial. It is easier to work with the trace I guess.

Comment: These two objects describe different things, geometrically, and both have their uses. The trace describes how (squared) lengths are transformed by $f$, while the determinant describes how (squared) volumes are transformed.