# Why is this called the conformal tensor?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors, conformal-geometry, isometry, diffeomorphism

Suppose you have a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ and a diffeomorphism $f: M \longrightarrow M$. Define $E^f:= f^*g - g$. I can understand that $E^f$ defines a $(0, 2)$-tensor which in a sense keeps record of everywhere that $f$ fails from being an isometry and by how much it does. However, I came across this other tensor:
$$
  E^f_C:= \text{tr}(f^*g)g
$$

which is called the conformal tensor. I was wondering if you could help with building the intuition of what it is really trying to describe.

---

You can find the above on pages 16 and 17 of this article: [Simultaneous Linearization of Diffeomorphisms of Isotropic Manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.08599)

Comment: A simple comment: the identity map $\operatorname{id} \colon (M,g) \to (M,E_C^f)$ is conformal. It might be the reason for the name, but I wouldn't know.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Actually, I did have the same thought since $g$ and $E^f_C$ are reading the same angles at every tangent space. The reason I got curious was that maybe, like $E^f$ that is quantitatively measuring some property about $f$, $E^f_C$ is trying to do a similar thing, i.e. why is it the trace that is important? It might be however just as you said. I mean, after all, the tensor just pops out during the computations of a proof and that might answer why are we taking the trace. Thanks anyways :-)

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3880939/272127) may be helpful.